# In which case we can use interpolation algorithm search instead binary search algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, binary-search-tree, interpolation

I have two sorted arrays:

```
$idProducts = [2,9,25,666,1001,1002,1005,2546...n]; //almost 55.000 values
$someIds =    [1,9,11,12,99,111,855...n]; //almost 2.500 values
```

I try make a new array from intersection of idProducts and $someIds.
I applied 3 search algorithms: linear, binary, interpolar searching, but only linear and binary algorithm work properly:

```
foreach($someIds as $id){
   if(interpolation_search($idProducts, $id) >=0){
        $newArray[]=$id;
   }
}
function interpolation_search($list, $x)
{
$l = 0;
$r = count($list) - 1;

while ($l <= $r) {
    if ($list[$l] == $list[$r]) {
        if ($list[$l] == $x) {
            return $l;
        } else {
            // not found
            return -1;
        }
    }

    $k = ($x - $list[$l])/($list[$r] - $list[$l]);

    // not found
    if ($k < 0 || $k > 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    $mid = round($l + $k*($r - $l));

    if ($x < $list[$mid]) {
        $r = $mid - 1;
    } else if ($x > $list[$mid]) {
        $l = $mid + 1;
    } else {
        // success!
        return $mid;
    }

    // not found
    return -1;
}
```

}

Anyway the best solution was:

```
$idProducts = array_flip($idProducts);
foreach ($someIds as $id){
   if (isset($idProducts [$id])===true){
            $newArray[]=$id;
   }
}
```

But i want know why interpolation doesnt work properly in my case and in which case we can implement interpolation algorithm searching.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to find intersection, you can use associative arrays. Better solution is to use 2 pointers which will be O(1) space.

Comment: Your algorithm works fine, just a minor mistake: move the last `return -1` two rows down, e.g. outside of the while loop.